# apache crashing

Tags: apache-2.2, server-crashes

Please help with some ideas about this Apache server crash:

Here is my MPM config and errors

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       5
MinSpareServers    30
MaxSpareServers   40
ServerLimit      950
MaxClients       950
MaxRequestsPerChild  2000
</IfModule>

[Sun Sep 09 03:08:03 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.16 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:47 2012] [error] [mod_pagespeed 0.10.22.4-1633 @5088] [0910/172647:ERROR:worker.cc(120)] Unable to start worker thread
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:48 2012] [error] [mod_pagespeed 0.10.22.4-1633 @4983] [0910/172648:ERROR:worker.cc(120)] Unable to start worker thread
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:48 2012] [error] [mod_pagespeed 0.10.22.4-1633 @4915] [0910/172648:ERROR:worker.cc(120)] Unable to start worker thread
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:49 2012] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 48
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:49 2012] [error] [mod_pagespeed 0.10.22.4-1633 @5095] [0910/172649:ERROR:worker.cc(120)] Unable to start worker thread
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:49 2012] [error] [mod_pagespeed 0.10.22.4-1633 @5085] [0910/172649:ERROR:worker.cc(120)] Unable to start worker thread
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:49 2012] [error] [mod_pagespeed 0.10.22.4-1633 @4989] [0910/172649:ERROR:worker.cc(120)] Unable to start worker thread
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:50 2012] [alert] Child 5108 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:50 2012] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:50 2012] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't release the accept mutex
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:50 2012] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't release the accept mutex
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:50 2012] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:50 2012] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:50 2012] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't release the accept mutex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most relevant error seems to be:

```
[Mon Sep 10 17:26:49 2012] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 48
```

Things just go downhill from there.

This means Apache hit the limit of the maximum number of processes allowed to run.

You can view the limit by running `ulimit -u`. To increase the limit, run `ulimit -u <number>` or edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` (probably Red Hat specific) and add a configuration directive for Apache's user to increase the value for `nproc` to something more reasonable.

You can also try reducing Apache's `ServerLimit` and `MaxClients` directives.

Comment: ulimit reports unlimited

Comment: It may be unlimited for root, but probably not for apache user! Be sure to check `/etc/security/limits.conf` or its equivalent if you aren't using a Red Hat derived distribution.

Comment: ulimit -s say 10240
everything is commented out in that file

Comment: ulimit -u 1024.. I am kind of learing about this limits so I don't really know what is a good value or what 1024 means (limit of opened files?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article explaining how RHEL6 introduced the maximum processes problem ("help ulimit" shows -u is "the maximum number of user processes") by adding the 1024 limit to /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf, which the author said he just commented out: http://kavassalis.com/2011/03/linux-and-the-maximum-number-of-processes-threads/

Here's the Red Hat Bugzilla page discussing it: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=432903

Comment: Explain why you immediately believe this to be a limits issue.

Comment: The article states that errno 11 from the setuid() call means the nproc limit was hit, which produces the error log message "[alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: setuid: unable to change to uid: 48".